# Unable to get the right Lat/Lang and IP in Sitecore using Maxmind

Tags: asp.net, .net, geolocation, sitecore, maxmind

I need help to get the current users lat/lang in SiteCore using Maxmin service.
I am trying with default config and with free lookups available.
I am using below API's to get the result.
    **Tracker.CurrentVisit.Latitude
    Tracker.CurrentVisit.Longitude**

But it gives me value zeero.

Actually when i try getting the IP using
    **Tracker.CurrentVisit.Ip**
,I got private IP but not the Public IP.
I deployed my solution in test server and accessing in local machine.
I don't have any license now, but what i understood that, there is some free look-ups available initially for few visits.
Also when i tried using the
    **Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp.Ip**
it failed because GeoIp is null.

What is the difference between **Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp.Ip**
and
**Tracker.CurrentVisit.Ip**
Please let me know if anyone has any inputs

-Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: If the server sees your private network IP Maxmind will not be able to give any information. For testing it is possible to modify the cached goe data in the analytics database. Look in the column "Cached" from the "GeoIps" table.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I believe the web service is not free.  The free version is a database (csv file) which you use locally.  You can find more information here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs

Comment: Thank you Chad. I think you are right. I am getting ",,,,,,,,,,LICENSE_EXPIRED" for the default value. I need to check after purchasing the license

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for Sitecore.Analytics.dll through ILSpy, Tracker.CurrentVisit.Ip returns the IP property on the analytics data row for the current session. It's a byte array, taken from the HTTP Request data I suspect. Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp returns the analytics database row for the GeoIP lookup for the current session. It is an object of the VisitorDataSet.GeoIpsRow type.

It's possible you're seeing empty data because of a configuration or licensing issue for the GeoIP service - but there's not enough information in your question for me to say much about that. However, with that service correctly configured, I'd had a potentially similar issue before - so maybe this will be of help:

You don't specify which version of Sitecore / DMS you're working with. But back in the day with DMS for v6.5/6.6, I hit some issues with GeoIP lookups because they were performed asynchronously.

When DMS created a new record for a visit, it would trigger the GeoIP lookup in the background - in parallel with serving the pages the user is requesting. You don't know when it will have succeeded and returned data, and the GeoIP properties in the Tracker object don't get correctly filled in until this has happened. So if you're trying to write code where you make geographic decisions during a user's first few page requests, they may not work properly.

I think (though I have not tested this) that you can use the Tracker.CurrentVisit.HasGeoIpData property to test if the async lookup has completed.

If you have a scenario where you need to know the GeoIP data during the user's first request, then I don't think the standard lookup service will be of use to you. There is an alternative in-memory tool you can use instead. I think the last time my company needed to do something like this we made use of some custom code based on this blog post: http://sitecoresnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/sitecore-geoip-country-resolving-jump.html

You trade off accuracy for speed by using this approach though. But on the other hand, you don't pay for each lookup...

Comment: Thanks JermDavis for the detail provided. I am using Sitecore 6.5 I am not sure how to check the DMS version.  think the problem here is I don't have required License for Maxmind service to use. Will get the License and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Maxmind is generally configured in the Sitecore.Analytics.config
You can test to see if your maxmind license returns a valid value:

```
<setting name="MaxMind.Url" value="http://sitecore1.maxmind.com/app/sc?i={0}&amp;l={1}" />
```

In the browser, take the url from the setting and put in a valid ip and add the license key (you can get the key on the login page.  Then append the value from MaxMind.SecurityToken).  Look for a return value.  There are a certain number of free requests, but after that you would need to pay.

Another item to look at is where the ip address is passed in the headers (real IP or X-forwarded for depending on your network).  Check this value

```
 <setting name="Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader" value="X-Forwarded-For" />
```

Comment: Thank you jmoynihan for teh iformation you provided. I tested the url with my License id and default Maxmind security Token (00000000) it it returned ",,,,,,,,,,LICENSE_EXPIRED". So i think I need to get the required license and test again this geolocation service

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sitecore.analytics.dll to get the current visit lat long, please see below code.

I am using this it will give you correct result.

```
var currentLat=Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit.Latitude;
var currentLong=Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit.Longitude;
```

If your site is hosted on your local system then it will give you zero result. Please host site on server then try, it will give you correct result.